# Dynamically group or filter objects within an array that share a given property name and value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to iterate through an `array loop` and do stuff according to the property name and value of the objects within the `array`.

The `array` is retrieved from a very "flat" `JSON` file, that is a collection of `git` commit logs from several `git` repositories (parsed to `JSON` from `bash` through [this project](https://github.com/dreamyguy/git-log-to-json/)).

Some of the things I would like to do would be:

- sort the commits by their timestamp.
- filter them by *repository*, and then do things with the data.
- filter them by *author_email*, and then do things with the data.
- calculate *impact* on each *repository* recursively.

But what I'm mostly interested in is **how can I select/group/filter all commits that share a certain property value (like *repository* or *author_email* or *date_day_week*) without specifying any explicit value?**

I have done it manually (see 7th line from bottom to top in the block of code below):

```
// == request and parse JSON data == //
// define data source
var data_source = "src/json/data.json";
// request the data
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", data_source);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState !== 4) { return; }
    if ((this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) || this.status === 0) {
        // get raw data
        data_JSON = this.responseText;
        // parse JSON data to JavaScript format
        data_parsed = JSON.parse(data_JSON);
        // manipulate data 'outside' the xhr request to keep things tidy
        manipulateData(data_parsed);
    } else {
        console.log('There was an error completing the XMLHttpRequest...');
    }
};
xhr.send();

// create a callback function to do stuff 'outside' xhr
function manipulateData(object){
    // define root object
    var commit = object.commits;
    // loop through every item so that we can iterate with them
    for (var i = 0; i < commit.length; i++){
        // define 'commit[i]' as 'item' so that code is more legible
        var item = commit[i];
        // list property names and their values on console
        for (var key in item) {
            if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                // list only items under 'lemon' repository <-- this is where I need it to be generic so I can group/filter all items under a common repository and do things with it
                if (item.repository == 'lemon') {
                    console.log(key + " -> " + item[key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But what I would like to do is to group/filter all commits that share a given property value (i.e. repository *lemon*, *apple*, *orange*, etc) together dynamically. Once I know how to do that, I'll hopefully be able to do the same with other property names that may share property values, like *author_email*, *date_day_week*, *date_month_name*, *insertions*, etc.

Below is the original `data.json` file, declared as a variable at `var data_source = "src/json/data.json";`:

```
{
    "commits":[
        {
            "repository":"lemon",
            "commit_nr":"1",
            "commit_hash":"146b76e91a269a9c06dcc4eb6854f76a7900a08e",
            "commit_hash_abbreviated":"146b76e",
            "tree_hash":"4090f728f1759a16df7dde49bf86f7536354ae02",
            "tree_hash_abbreviated":"4090f72",
            "parent_hashes":"",
            "parent_hashes_abbreviated":"",
            "author_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "date_day_week":"Fri",
            "date_month_name":"Feb",
            "date_month_day":"25",
            "date_hour":"09:59:17",
            "date_year":"2011",
            "date_hour_gmt":"-0800",
            "author_date_unix_timestamp":"1298656757",
            "date_iso_8601":"2011-02-25",
            "committer_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "files_changed":"46",
            "insertions":"3162",
            "deletions":"",
            "impact":"3162"
        },
        {
            "repository":"lemon",
            "commit_nr":"2",
            "commit_hash":"d6c8de134e0ee33b3837795250c9fffa02e57738",
            "commit_hash_abbreviated":"d6c8de1",
            "tree_hash":"f4ec855ed6c4402304500a68a74ff38943a47d3d",
            "tree_hash_abbreviated":"f4ec855",
            "parent_hashes":"146b76e91a269a9c06dcc4eb6854f76a7900a08e",
            "parent_hashes_abbreviated":"146b76e",
            "author_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "date_day_week":"Fri",
            "date_month_name":"Feb",
            "date_month_day":"25",
            "date_hour":"11:27:24",
            "date_year":"2011",
            "date_hour_gmt":"-0800",
            "author_date_unix_timestamp":"1298662044",
            "date_iso_8601":"2011-02-25",
            "committer_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "files_changed":"5",
            "insertions":"46",
            "deletions":"40",
            "impact":"6"
        },
        {
            "repository":"lemon",
            "commit_nr":"3",
            "commit_hash":"9a27e12968397923df17a424672447eee06ea248",
            "commit_hash_abbreviated":"9a27e12",
            "tree_hash":"5ceb1539ee9879f7d9043123ee36c4c44c93e64c",
            "tree_hash_abbreviated":"5ceb153",
            "parent_hashes":"d6c8de134e0ee33b3837795250c9fffa02e57738",
            "parent_hashes_abbreviated":"d6c8de1",
            "author_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "date_day_week":"Fri",
            "date_month_name":"Feb",
            "date_month_day":"25",
            "date_hour":"11:52:09",
            "date_year":"2011",
            "date_hour_gmt":"-0800",
            "author_date_unix_timestamp":"1298663529",
            "date_iso_8601":"2011-02-25",
            "committer_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "files_changed":"6",
            "insertions":"151",
            "deletions":"81",
            "impact":"70"
        },
        {
            "repository":"apple",
            "commit_nr":"1",
            "commit_hash":"61180570cb0cbc2233f841436d924ab43eeb7c7e",
            "commit_hash_abbreviated":"6118057",
            "tree_hash":"f652101ca189f92fc70767203879af9aeb9cec1e",
            "tree_hash_abbreviated":"f652101",
            "parent_hashes":"",
            "parent_hashes_abbreviated":"",
            "author_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "date_day_week":"Fri",
            "date_month_name":"Oct",
            "date_month_day":"1",
            "date_hour":"17:01:48",
            "date_year":"2010",
            "date_hour_gmt":"+0700",
            "author_date_unix_timestamp":"1285927308",
            "date_iso_8601":"2010-10-01",
            "committer_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "files_changed":"0",
            "insertions":"",
            "deletions":"",
            "impact":"0"
        },
        {
            "repository":"apple",
            "commit_nr":"2",
            "commit_hash":"3d3d52f0197aa501c9c4d6e4c245604e696097e1",
            "commit_hash_abbreviated":"3d3d52f",
            "tree_hash":"a1e190dfc9e63c7895884fbc9c1cbfa1473a27c2",
            "tree_hash_abbreviated":"a1e190d",
            "parent_hashes":"61180570cb0cbc2233f841436d924ab43eeb7c7e",
            "parent_hashes_abbreviated":"6118057",
            "author_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "date_day_week":"Mon",
            "date_month_name":"Oct",
            "date_month_day":"11",
            "date_hour":"11:30:08",
            "date_year":"2010",
            "date_hour_gmt":"+0700",
            "author_date_unix_timestamp":"1286771408",
            "date_iso_8601":"2010-10-11",
            "committer_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "files_changed":"24",
            "insertions":"452",
            "deletions":"",
            "impact":"452"
        },
        {
            "repository":"apple",
            "commit_nr":"3",
            "commit_hash":"1b5b80db7dd8a252d40b6331ba7ba85dd4af90c6",
            "commit_hash_abbreviated":"1b5b80d",
            "tree_hash":"89d70a6ac4b071aea13055f91a9907c6480e99d3",
            "tree_hash_abbreviated":"89d70a6",
            "parent_hashes":"3d3d52f0197aa501c9c4d6e4c245604e696097e1",
            "parent_hashes_abbreviated":"3d3d52f",
            "author_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "date_day_week":"Mon",
            "date_month_name":"Oct",
            "date_month_day":"11",
            "date_hour":"14:17:47",
            "date_year":"2010",
            "date_hour_gmt":"+0700",
            "author_date_unix_timestamp":"1286781467",
            "date_iso_8601":"2010-10-11",
            "committer_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "files_changed":"1",
            "insertions":"15",
            "deletions":"",
            "impact":"15"
        },
        {
            "repository":"orange",
            "commit_nr":"1",
            "commit_hash":"dac34582a10de94cd305afc47cd888ee59c30e35",
            "commit_hash_abbreviated":"dac3458",
            "tree_hash":"9114b1b23157894f3fac49ecd7686aadc2cc7678",
            "tree_hash_abbreviated":"9114b1b",
            "parent_hashes":"",
            "parent_hashes_abbreviated":"",
            "author_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "date_day_week":"Tue",
            "date_month_name":"Feb",
            "date_month_day":"4",
            "date_hour":"01:24:51",
            "date_year":"2014",
            "date_hour_gmt":"-0800",
            "author_date_unix_timestamp":"1391505891",
            "date_iso_8601":"2014-02-04",
            "committer_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "files_changed":"1",
            "insertions":"4",
            "deletions":"",
            "impact":"4"
        },
        {
            "repository":"orange",
            "commit_nr":"2",
            "commit_hash":"077fa1e30bfb1b02241d8fd603941a250ded983d",
            "commit_hash_abbreviated":"077fa1e",
            "tree_hash":"d8eb6b28fd3798b0490fd7376c29781cdaffd42d",
            "tree_hash_abbreviated":"d8eb6b2",
            "parent_hashes":"dac34582a10de94cd305afc47cd888ee59c30e35",
            "parent_hashes_abbreviated":"dac3458",
            "author_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "date_day_week":"Wed",
            "date_month_name":"Feb",
            "date_month_day":"5",
            "date_hour":"20:24:48",
            "date_year":"2014",
            "date_hour_gmt":"+0700",
            "author_date_unix_timestamp":"1391606688",
            "date_iso_8601":"2014-02-05",
            "committer_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "files_changed":"9",
            "insertions":"374",
            "deletions":"",
            "impact":"374"
        },
        {
            "repository":"orange",
            "commit_nr":"3",
            "commit_hash":"e217e8d4b4e366331d5e2a196215867c60215bfc",
            "commit_hash_abbreviated":"e217e8d",
            "tree_hash":"95d4002df3db4d0f3912b0609a3680dd3d751a92",
            "tree_hash_abbreviated":"95d4002",
            "parent_hashes":"077fa1e30bfb1b02241d8fd603941a250ded983d",
            "parent_hashes_abbreviated":"077fa1e",
            "author_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "date_day_week":"Thu",
            "date_month_name":"Feb",
            "date_month_day":"6",
            "date_hour":"14:44:00",
            "date_year":"2014",
            "date_hour_gmt":"+0700",
            "author_date_unix_timestamp":"1391672640",
            "date_iso_8601":"2014-02-06",
            "committer_email":"bogus@name.com",
            "files_changed":"1",
            "insertions":"1",
            "deletions":"3",
            "impact":"-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are going to do inside that if statement? I'm trying to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If you just want to group what you received you could create an new array and have the first dimension be the repository. i.e. `yourarray[repository].push(item)`

Comment: @Dan once I have filtered/grouped a set of object *name* & *value*, I'll be able to iterate through the items and do things like [render graphs as these](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/tutorial/introduction.html). ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
function groupBy(data,key, val){
    var arr=[];
    for(var i in data){
        if(data[i][key]==val) arr.push(data[i])
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(groupBy(object.commits,"repository","lemon"))
```

And for grouping without specifying `val`:

```
function groupByAuto(data, key){
    var groups={};
    for(var i in data){
        if(!groups.hasOwnProperty(data[i][key])) groups[data[i][key]]=[];
        groups[data[i][key]].push(data[i]);
    }
    return groups;
}
console.log(groupByAuto(data.commits, "repository"))
```

Comment: I must say this was pretty smartly done! It worked with other sets of `key` x `val` as well (like `author_email`)! But would there be any way to create separate arrays for each grouped `val` automatically, by running a modified function like: `groupByAuto(object.commits, "repository")`. The nature of this data is such that I don't know which values will be listed (though `key` won't change) - so it would really save me a lot of time not to have to specify `val`, in this case.

Comment: Something like "loop through the specified `data.key` (like `object.commits.repository`) and create a new array when it finds a `val`. if (previous `val` === current `val`) add it to array, otherwise keep creating new arrays - as long as there is a new `val`"... To be honest I don't know how I would do this, nor if it is the best approach. Hence the question. :P

Comment: You would only have to alter the if statement for this. `if(data[i][key] in arr) { //add to existing array } else { // create new array }`

Comment: @WallaceSidhrée added `groupByAuto` function to answer

Comment: @juvian this is absolutely gorgeous code! I've made a [simplified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamyguy/TZ633/) applying both your answers, so that others might see how useful this is. This is greatly appreciated, now I can move on to the next step! Cheers!!